# Why thead content is not repeating in each and every print page while I try to print the web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have a table and I'm trying to print it. It's working fine in the normal mode but when I rotate my `th` then it is visible in the first print page but not visible on other pages.

```css
th span {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><span style="transform-origin: 0 50%;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;">Firstname</span></th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Screenshot of first and second print page:**

First print page:

[image]

Second print page:

[image]

**Note: This is working when I remove rotate `span` from `th`**

What is missing?

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want to rotate the `th`?

Comment: @R.D This is client requirement, actually in `thead` more than 15 th then we have only one option to print it in A4 paper size.

Comment: Alright hold on. Let me see.

Comment: Alright I solved it, just one thing. Part of the `First name` is being printed on the first page as well. Since it is actually a continuation of the entire th name so there is no way to remove it unless you change the th name. Is that solution acceptable to you? Then I will post it @Rohit

Comment: But it is strange. I cannot see the error you are seeing when i am using your code. What browser are you using?

Comment: Actually i got prefect answer for it.

Comment: adding a margin, affecting the table from the top of the page wouldnt make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer it is fixed now & working fine because of now I use `CSS` in print script code instead of normal CSS.

Comment: Please, could you clarify your answer?

Comment: @Salketer Actually i was using style direct in CSS but now i'm using css in print script where i code for print. So now working fine

Answer (score 9):

Some browsers repeat the thead element on each page, as they are supposed to. But some browsers will not, you need to add extra css for your table header as

```
thead {display: table-header-group;}
```

**Note:** Opera 7.5 and IE 5 won't repeat headers no matter what you try.

Answer (score 2):

For Print you may use separate CSS.

Add the code inside the print media like below.

```
@media print {

    // Your code here

}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to give your `th` some padding

```
th {
    padding: 3em;
}
```

[What my print looks like after I add padding to th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJBCY.png)